# Braintree's Sandbox PayPal Integration (using JS and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal, braintree

I currently working on integrating braintree to my company's website, but only for PayPal orders. I am currently using braintree's sandbox. When I try to setup braintree, I use shippingAddressOverride to set the test shipping address. However, I've been getting the default shipping address returned back to me.

```
<?php
require_once '_environment.php';
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="paypal-container"></div> 
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
    <script>
        braintree.setup("<?php print $clientToken; ?>", "custom", {
            paypal: {
                container: "paypal-container",
                singleUse: true, // Required
                amount: 10.00, // Required
                currency: 'USD', // Required
                locale: 'en_us',
                enableShippingAddress: 'true',
                shippingAddressOverride: {
                    recipientName: 'Scruff McGruff',
                    streetAddress: '1234 Main St.',
                    extendedAddress: 'Unit 1',
                    locality: 'Chicago',
                    countryCodeAlpha2: 'US',
                    postalCode: '60652',
                    region: 'IL',
                    phone: '123.456.7890',
                    editable: false
                }
            },
            onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
                //doSomethingWithTheNonce(obj.nonce);
                console.log(obj.details.shippingAddress);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a reason why I keep getting the default shipping address instead of the one that is set?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.</sub>

This is a known issue and Braintree devs are investigating it. For now, if you need the shippingAddressOverride functionality I would suggest rolling back to an earlier release. You can follow progress on resolving this at the [GitHub issue that has been opened](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/issues/119). If you have any further questions, please contact [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I tried to use an older version of braintree.js, and in version 2.7.1 it working!
Maybe in newest releases of Braintree something broke:(